# UIBarButtonItems in UIToolbar are not sizing to the height of the toolbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uikit

Here's what I'm trying:

```
_textInputToolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320.0, 44.0)];
    [_textInputToolBar setAutoresizesSubviews:YES];
    UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace
                                                                                   target:self
                                                                                   action:nil];

    UIBarButtonItem *previousButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow-left"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(userDidPressPrevious:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *nextButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"arrow-right"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(userDidPressNext:)];

    [_textInputToolBar setItems:@[flexibleSpace, previousButton, nextButton]];
```

[image]

I've also tried UIButton inside customView of UIBarButtonItem.  That works but won't give me the tint colors of enabled and disabled that you get from the UIBarButtonItem.  There has to be something I'm missing that is not sizing down the images inside the UIBarButtonItem.

Comment: What are your images size ?. And the name, the files names should be arrow-left@2x.png and arrow-right@2x.png. The right size must be 44x44pixels

Comment: Thanks, at least now I realize the image has to be forced downsized, figured the UIBarButtonItem would do that.